# Liquibase Oracle: Generate changelog tries to create objects from another schema

Tags: oracle, liquibase

I want to generate a changelog XML from an existing Oracle schema, let's name it `A`. This schema contains references to another schema, schema `B`. Tables in schema `A` for example contain foreign keys referencing tables in schema `B`. User `A` has only `SELECT` and  `REFERENCES` privileges on the tables of schema `B`.

When I try to create a database changelog for schema `A`, tables and constraints from `B` are included, even though they are not owned by user `A`. Is there any way to change this behavior? I tries to set the `defaultCatalogName`, `defaultSchemaName`, `changelogCatalogName` and `changelogSchemaName` parameters, but nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work the way you expect, but due to bug https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1784 it is not working as expected. It is fixed for the upcoming 3.2.0 release, probably out in mid March.

Comment: Thank you, I just wanted a confirmation before opening a new bug.